# Get season number for each player in DF

Tags: r

I have a df with the following columns: Name, Season Year, Yds.

I am trying to create a 4th column that says the number of the season for each player.

ex - L.Bell , 2012, 343

L.Bell , 2013, 367

B.Hall, 2022, 0

I would want row 1 col 4 to say 1, and row 2 col 4 to say 2, and now row 3 col 4 to say 1 again since it is for a new player.

Thanks

Comment: please see the answers below, if one of them solved your problem, please upvote and accept it, otherwise feel free to use the comment-section to ask for further help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `order` in `ave` to get the number of seasons.

```
x$Season <- ave(x$SeasonYear, x$Name, FUN=order)
x
#    Name SeasonYear Yds Season
#1 L.Bell       2012 343      1
#2 L.Bell       2013 367      2
#3 B.Hall       2022   0      1
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame(Name = c("L.Bell", "L.Bell", "B.Hall")
              , SeasonYear = c(2012, 2013, 2022)
              , Yds = c(343, 367, 0) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>% group_by(Name) %>% mutate(Season = rank(Year))
```

Edit: Using base-R one can instead do:

```r
df$season <- NA
split(df$season, df$Name) <- lapply(split(df$year, df$Name), rank)
```